# Memory leak problem 

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I am getting leak at:

```
NSString *searchText = [aSearchBar.text 
    stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet 
    whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Can anyone suggest how to get out of this memory leak.

Comment: Why are you using `NSCFString`?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake it was NSString.Now I edited it.

Comment: How are you noticing the leak? The leaks tool in Instruments, the static analyzer or what? Because I don't see how that line by itself could leak unless you're missing an autorelease pool.

Comment: @Chuck:Im noticing it by leaks tool in instruments.

Comment: Yeah I used the autorelease pool even though it showing leak at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

That one line isn't leaking anything. If you do have a leak, it's somewhere else in your code.